# SharePoint restore deleted document set from 1st stage recycle bin to a site which is over or at capacity

Tags: sharepoint

**Background:**

We have a SharePoint site where if you attempt to restore a deleted item, you get an error stating the site is at or above capacity.  We cannot reach the site contents (times out).

We have attempted to delete numerous other document sets to clear space for restoring items that were inadvertently deleted to no avail.

---

**Inquiry:**

Is there a way to forcibly restore (even from an admin) a deleted file, even if SharePoint indicates the site is at capacity?

---

**Image of error:**

[image]